# how to get items from a dictionary of lists with linq

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, linq-to-objects

I don't really understand LINQ. I every example I find is overly simplified to the point where I don't know why you would even use LINQ for it, or too complicated that I need to already know how LINQ works in order to understand it.

So I'm wondering if and how you would use LINQ to this... In this example let's say you have a list of player classes, and inside of each class there is a list of abilities. Each ability has a level requirement. How can you use LINQ to select all abilities that are at or below a certain level for a set of specific classes?

Giveen this data:

- Class1

  - Ability1 - Level 1
  - Ability2 - Level 5
  - Ability3 - Level 9
- Class2

  - Ability4 - Level 1
  - Ability5 - Level 2
  - Ability6 - Level 6
- Class3

  - Ability7 - Level 2
  - Ability8 - Level 4
  - Ability9 - Level 6

I want a list of all abilities for Class1 & Class3 that are level 5 or below. The result should be { Ability1, Ability2, Ability7, Ability8 }.

```
public class Class1
{

  public class Ability
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
  }

  public class PlayerClass
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Ability> Abilities { get; set; }
  }

  public List<PlayerClass> Classes { get; set; }

  public Class1()
  {
    PlayerClass oClass;

    Classes = new List<PlayerClass>();

    oClass = new PlayerClass();
    oClass.Name = "Class1";
    oClass.Abilities = new List<Ability>();
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability1", Level = 1 });
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability2", Level = 5 });
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability3", Level = 9 });
    Classes.Add(oClass);

    oClass = new PlayerClass();
    oClass.Name = "Class2";
    oClass.Abilities = new List<Ability>();
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability4", Level = 1 });
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability5", Level = 2 });
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability6", Level = 6 });
    Classes.Add(oClass);

    oClass = new PlayerClass();
    oClass.Name = "Class3";
    oClass.Abilities = new List<Ability>();
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability7", Level = 2 });
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability8", Level = 4 });
    oClass.Abilities.Add(new Ability() { Name = "Ability9", Level = 6 });
    Classes.Add(oClass);

    IEnumerable<Ability> Abilities = 
                   GetAbilitiesForClasses("Class1;Class3".Split(';'), 5);
    //Abilities should contain Ability1, Ability2, Ability7, Ability8
  }

  public IEnumerable<Ability> GetAbilitiesForClasses
       (string[] asClassNames, int iLevel)
  {
    // TODO: Use LINQ to return the abilities for the class names 
           //contained in asClassNames that are at or below level: iLevel
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you posted the defintions (in c#) of your classes with some sample data, you would get much more and faster answers.

Comment: LINQ is beautiful. Readability, less code, better processing.

Comment: yes you should be more specific, what is Ability( class, ...)

Comment: I did include sample data, and I did describe the classes in the question... I said I have a list of classes (List<Class>) and each class contains a list of abilities(Class.Abilities is a List<Ability>) and each Ability has a level (Ability.Level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Ability> GetAbilitiesForClasses(string[] asClassNames, int iLevel)
{
    return Classes
           .Where(X => asClassNames.Contains(X.Name))
           .SelectMany(X => X.Abilities)
           .Where(X => X.Level <= iLevel)
           .ToList();
}
```

Comment: +1, though this assumes that the various classes implement `IEnumerable<Ability>`

Comment: Not necessarily- the enumerable could be a property of Class1, Class2, etc.

Comment: that's right, so it'll `Class1.Abilities.Union(Class2.Abilities).Union(Class3.Abilities).Where(X=>X.Level<=5).ToList()`

Comment: This is exactly what I came up with too after seeing the answers from other people.

Comment: actually i just used var not List<Ability> and then the .ToList() at the end. that's extra unnecessary data copying.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your player class is represented by a `PlayerClass` class, with an `Abilities` property of type `IDictionary<string, int>`:

```
List<PlayerClass> classes = ...
var results =
    from c in classes
    where c.Name == "Class1" || c.Name == "Class2"
    from ab in c.Abilities // ab is of type KeyValuePair<string, int>
    where ab.Value <= 5
    select ab.Key;
```

But it would be better to define an `Ability` class with `Name` and `Level` properties; the `Abilities` property would then be an `IList<Ability>`:

```
List<PlayerClass> classes = ...
var results =
    from c in classes
    where c.Name == "Class1" || c.Name == "Class2"
    from ab in c.Abilities
    where ab.Level <= 5
    select ab.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just storing Abilities you could  consolidate them into one structure and have a List of classes which you can perform `LINQ` on.

For example:

```
public List<AbilityClass> Abilities { get; set; }
```

*LINQ:*

```
 var level9Abilities = (from a in Abilities
                    where.Level == "Level 9"
                 // where a.Level > 9 (if Level is an int)
                  select a).ToList();


 foreach (var lvl in level9Abilities) {
      Console.WriteLine(lvl);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SelectMany`, assume:

```
 public class Class
{
    public List<Ability> Abilities { get; set; }
}

public class Ability
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

Use Linq:

```
var classes = new List<Class>() {class1, class3};

var output = classes.SelectMany(c => c.Abilities)
            .Where(a => a.Level <= 5);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about SelectMany. I like that.